# Speed vs Quality UI Pattern

Tags: controls, response-time, sliders

I'm trying to come up with a good disposition of UI elements to help depict Function Speed vs Quality.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

- Are the Labels Right / Informative Enough?
- Is the Slider the Right Control?

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJFjFm.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think the slider's acceptable, but you should lead with the benefits, so it looks something like:

```
Faster Running Time |-----X---|---------| Better Quality
```

People are smart enough to understand they're sacrificing one for the other, or at least not dumb enough to think they're going to get both.

Comment: +1 That's exactly the kind of insight I'm looking for... Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

Slider is the right control. Simplify the text to just the words Speed/Quality.

You could add a second visual to to represent the time. This would change size as you moved the slider accentuating the trade-off. The total length should represent the longest possible time. However this is a nice to have (;

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fI2ZsC.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Comment: Beautiful Suggestion! :)

Answer (score 1):

You might take cues from Photoshops jpeg save options which presents a similar tradeoff, file size (economy) vs. image quality.  When the slider is slid 2 things also change, the number in the Quality box (currently showing "10" here) and the file size (to the right of the slider, "619.4K" here), so the user gets feedback on what the slider setting means. (This is an old, 2008 version of Photoshop, but that's still 20 years of refinement!)

[image: Photoshops jpeg save settings]

Comment: Hi Obelia, I actually looked at this and to microsoft internet security settings to give me an idea, but didn't like the examples, I think they were a little bit convoluted... I'm still trying to remember good examples of it, but the answers in this post are being brilliant so far.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another idea based on [Rachel Keslensky](https://ux.stackexchange.com/users/21575/rachel-keslensky) and [Lisa Tweedie](https://ux.stackexchange.com/users/15475/lisa-tweedie) answers, just for the sake of enjoyment! :)

However, as I see it this is not a standard control.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f7bq0q.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Comment: I quite like that idea. It gives equal weight to the two variables and reinforces the weighting. 

Compared to my solution it loses the explicit link with the exact quantity time. In my design I focused on that because I made the assumption that this may be the variable people would most be interested. This may be incorrect of course!

Answer (score 0):

I would add "quality" label is suffisent than "better quality" and "running time" rather "faster running time"